# Vector space isomorphic to direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a basis for the infinite dimensional space $V$. Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of copies of the field $F$ indexed by the set $A.$ Prove that the direct product of copies of $F$ indexed by $A$ is a vector space over $F$ and it has strictly larger dimension than the dimension of $V.$

Answer (score 1):

> Prove that $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of copies of the field $F$ indexed by the set $A$.

This is the definition of basis.

> Prove that the direct product of copies of $F$ indexed by $A$ is a vector space over $F$ and it has strictly larger dimension than the dimension of $V$.

Here use Cantor's diagonal argument.